# Complex numbers: With conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

I've just started calculating complex numbers (last time I calculated with complex numbers was in high school) and I've already got stuck at this exercise:

> $$3z-i\bar z = 7-5i$$

where $\bar z$ is the conjugate of z.

What I've tested so far is to set $z=x+yi$

and with further calculations I've reached this equation

$$3(x+yi)-i(x-yi)=7-5i \implies 3x+3yi-xi+yi^2=7-5i$$

The result should be $z=2-i$.

Comment: You can format your answers at MSE with $\LaTeX!$. Read basic manual at [this meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have as your last equation
$$ 3x + 3yi - xi + yi^2 = 7-5i$$
now $i^2 = -1$, so we have
$$ 3x-y + (3y - x)i = 7-5i$$
Now as $x$ and $y$ are real, we must have (as complex numbers are equal iff both real and imaginary parts are)
$$ 3x-y = 7 \land 3y - x = -5 $$
This is a linear system for $x$ and $y$ which has $x = 2$ and $y = -1$ as its solution. Hence $z = x+yi = 2-i$.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

Start with the given equation

$3z-i\overline z = 7-5i$.

Any root of this equation must also solve the conjugate equation

$3\overline z-iz = 7+5i$.

The second equation forces $\overline z=[7+(z+5)i]/3$, so the original equation becomes by substitution

$3z-i[7+(z+5)i]/3 = 7-5i$.

This contains only $z$ and can be solved by the usual methods for linear equations to give $\color{blue}{z=2-i}$.

As a final step, check by direct evaluation that this root satisfies the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

If we know $i^2=-1$ and $x+iy=a+ib\iff x=a,y=b$

$$3x-y+i(3y-x)=7-5i$$

So, $3x-y=7$ and $3y-x=-5$

Answer (score 0):

[too long for a comment]

Since the complex number $ \ z \ = \ a + bi \ $ can be treated as the vector $ \ \langle a \ , \ b \rangle \ $ in the Argand plane, an equation of this sort is equivalent to a vector equation.  We have the transformations $ \ \overline{z} \ \rightarrow \ \langle a \ , \ -b \rangle \ \ , \ $ $ \ iz  \ \rightarrow \ \langle -b \ , \ a \rangle \ \   $ (90º CCW rotation), and $ \ -iz  \ \rightarrow \ \langle b \ , \ -a \rangle \ \   $ (90º CW rotation).  So $ \ 3z - i\overline{z} \ = \ 7 - 5i \ $ can be solved as $ \ 3 \langle a \ , \ b \rangle \ - \ \langle b \ , \ a \rangle \  = \ \langle 7 \ , \ -5 \rangle \ \ , \ $ using your preferred linear algebra technique.