# How to solve $3z - i\overline{z}=7-5i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve this equation: $3z - i\overline{z}=7-5i$ and I am stuck.
I start with changing $z=a+bi$ and $\overline{z}=a-bi$
$3(a+bi) - i(a-bi)=7-5i$
$3a+3bi - (ia-bi^2)=7-5i$
$3a+3bi - ia+bi^2=7-5i$
$3a+3bi - ia-b=7-5i$
And now I don't really know what to do next but I have tried this:
$3a- ia+3bi -b=7-5i$
$a(3- i)+b(3i -1)=7-5i$
$a(3- i)+b(-1+3i )=7-5i$
How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Compare real and imaginary parts to get two simultaneous equations in $a,b$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex numbers: With conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250758/complex-numbers-with-conjugate)

Comment: Although slightly different, you may try $b=\frac{7-5 i}{3i-1},a=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to go with the real and imaginary parts. If you know that
$$
3z-i\bar{z}=7-5i
$$
then you know that the same relation holds also for the conjugates
$$
3\bar{z}+iz=7+5i
$$
Multiply the second equation by $i$ and the first equation by $3$:
\begin{cases}
9z-3i\bar{z}=21-15i \\[6px]
-z+3i\bar{z}=7i-5
\end{cases}
Can you finish?

Comment: (+1) but this solution was present in the duplicate previously mentionned above.

Comment: @AnneBauval I didn't see it, but I believe that elimination is better (and faster).

Answer (score 4):

Collect the real terms and imaginary terms like so:

$$(3a-b)-(a+b)i = 7-5i$$

Now, compare the real terms on the left hand side to real terms on the right hand side:
$3a-b=7$

Now, do the same for the imaginary terms:
$a+b=5$

You can now solve these simultaneously to get the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This solution is wrong and anyway useless: better look at the duplicate previously mentionned above.

Comment: @AnneBauval Why is it wrong?I got the right answer when I used the method provided in this answer.

Comment: The right answer is $a=2,b=-1,$ so $a+b=1\ne5.$ Look at the duplicate linked above.

Comment: The imaginary part in the first equation is $3b-a$, not $-a-b$